# What is the reason for memory leak in simple webapp?

Tags: java, tomcat, memory-leaks

Very simple webapp, but tomcat finds memory leak after undeploy.

> The following web applications were stopped (reloaded, undeployed),
>   but their classes from previous runs are still loaded in memory, thus
>   causing a memory leak (use a profiler to confirm): /WEBSearchPrime_3

What is the reason?

```
package mainThread;

public class GeneralThread implements Runnable {

    private boolean stop = false;

    @Override
    public void run() {

        while (!Thread.interrupted()) {

            try {
                Thread.sleep( 1000 );
            } catch (InterruptedException e) { }

            if(isStop()) {
                System.out.println("Exit");
                return;
            }
            System.out.println("DO TASK");
        }
    }

    public boolean isStop() {
        return stop;
    }

    public synchronized void setStop() {
        this.stop = true;
    }

}

package mainThread;

import javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent;
import javax.servlet.ServletContextListener;

public class AppServletContextListener implements ServletContextListener {

    Thread thread;
    GeneralThread generalThread;

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent arg0) {  
        generalThread = new GeneralThread();
        thread = new Thread(generalThread);
        thread.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent arg0) {

        generalThread.setStop();
        thread.interrupt();

        try {
            thread.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("Context destroyed!");
        if(thread.isAlive()) System.out.println("thread is still alive...");
    }
}
```

Comment: Does the webapp print "Exit" and not ""thread is still alive..."?

Comment: yes, it prints:
`Exit
Context destroyed!
march 30, 2014 3:50:45 PM org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler destroyApplication
INFO: Undeploying app: C:\apache-tomee-webprofile-1.6.0\webapps\WEBSearchPrime_3
march 30, 2014 3:50:46 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deleteRedeployResources
INFO: Undeploying context [/WEBSearchPrime_3]`